# All whitespace removed and plain text when pasting in all input and text fields

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, addeventlistener, plaintext, clipboarddata

I have seen a few of these question on here and I can not seem to get this to work.

Basically I want the copy and paste events to be plain text only and to remove all white space apart from line breaks and text spaces within the copy and paste process.

(whitespace meaning anything that can not be done using the enter key or spacebar... Things like the tab key etc.)

I need this to happen because this section will be going into a json, and without doing this, it will break the json string.

I will be doing other checks regarding quotes etc.

[You can see a jfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/robertg/awm2kgzx/10/)

Here is the code I have used:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

"use strict";

document.querySelector("input, textarea").addEventListener("paste", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var text = e.clipboardData.getData("text/plain");
    text = text.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,'');
    document.execCommand("insertHTML", false, text);
});
```

});

Thanks in advance for any help provided.

Comment: "all white space apart from line breaks and text spaces"....line breaks are not whitespace, they're special characters. And what other whitespace do you consider not to be "text spaces"? Do you mean space at the start/end of the string? Or double spaces between words? Or something else? Please be specific. Also I see no reason why any of this would "break" JSON, if it's inserted correctly. If you have an actual example of the issue you're facing, please show it so we can understand the real problem. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @ADyson sorry for not being specific enough, basically I was talking about anything that can not be done using the enter key or spacebar, so things like tabs and other things that microsoft word and other editors might introduce when copy and pasting

Comment: Ok. You could perhaps use a more complex Regular Expression for that. You haven't really explained a situation where your current code is failing to meet your expectations? What goes wrong with it?

Comment: But anyway...why is any of this causing problems with JSON? If you're capturing the textarea value as a string and inserting it into an object, and then serialising that to JSON, then it's hard to see what issue it could be causing, unless perhaps you've got some non-UTF8 characters in there or something. Again, give us a specific example of some data which is presenting an issue, and also show us how you're turning this into (part of) a JSON object, and what the result is (any why you consider that result to be a problem).

Comment: Thank you again for taking time to help, the issue is when using copy and paste from word using some special characters they use like the non UTF8, basically I will hopefully find a regex that removes anything that will break the json string.

I will putting it within an array and then converting it to json using the JSON.stringify()

Comment: I'd say restricting to plain text, line breaks and whitespace is perhaps too restrictive. If you focus on non-UTF8 characters, which is the real issue, then there are [a lot of suggestions](https://www.google.com/search?safe=active&ei=6yOiW9CKFIaYsAf2kJe4BA&q=javascript+remove+non+utf-8+characters&oq=javascript+remove+non+utf-8+characters&gs_l=psy-ab.3..35i39k1.35529.36503.0.36615.10.10.0.0.0.0.116.752.7j2.9.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..4.6.498...0i7i30k1j0i13k1.0.PI5yYYP844k) out there already. Have you looked into that at all?

Comment: @ADyson I did try removing all non utf8 chars and I was still getting broken json string because of a whitespace issue, or at least that is what it looked like as I could not see the code, it was just a space and a linebreak all in one, which I assumed was a tab effect

Comment: whitespace would not break JSON. nor would a tab character, to my knowledge. If you'd like help with that, please give us a specific example which we can use to reproduce the issue. And what do you mean "I could not see the code..."? you can inspect the data which your code produces quite easily using the browser tools

Comment: I will try and get an example of what was going on, and what I was seeing.

Even with the browser tools, its was not showing anything but space, with nothing else that could be breaking it.

Again thank you for taking your time to help, It may take me a while to find the email sent to me that broke the json string. :)

Comment: if you have something like Notepad++, you can paste the problem text into there and tell it to display special characters, so things like line breaks, tabs etc will be visible.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).on('paste', 'textarea', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var text = e.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData('Text');
  text = text.trim();
  text = text.replace(/\s+/g,' ').trim();
  $(this).val(text);
});
```

@Robert You can use the `.trim()` function which can only remove starting and ending spaces.
You can replace `text = text.trim();` with `text = text.replace(/\s+/g,' ').trim();` and it will work for inner text too.
I think that's it what u want.
If you want anything then fell free to asked.

Comment: This is ok if you only have 1 textarea but as soon as you have multiple, then you get an error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getData' of undefined.

Also I need to trim curtain whitespaces within the string not just before or after.

Thank you for taking your time to send an answer

Comment: what you mean as multiple text area will you please elaborate i did't get it. If i create 3 text area and paste the text it did't give me any error i think i'm in wrong path will you clarify it.

Comment: @Urocks I agree, your code will not produce that kind of error - see http://jsfiddle.net/a5rzuvts/2/

Comment: @Robert Take a look at new answer it will fully help you & Thank you #ADyson for appreciation.

Answer (score 0):

**Try Following**

```js
$(document).on('paste', 'textarea', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var PlainText = e.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData('Text');
  PlainText = PlainText.replace(/\s+/g, '');
  $(this).val(PlainText);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea placeholder="Paste Your Text..."></textarea >
```

Comment: this appears to remove _all_ whitespace, which I doubt is the desired effect. And it also seems to remove line breaks, which the question specifically said should be preserved.

Comment: This also only works on the first instance of a textarea, the very next textarea gives the following error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getData' of undefined